# Book involving fog and primordial soup

Tags: story-identification

I read a book back in middle school. Can't remember the name of the book or the author or anything. Tried googling all the stuff I remember, but nothing ever fit it. It had a biohazard symbol on the cover, and it was sort of holographic, a bunch of whites and blues, looked kind of like how people interpret dream sequences or warp jumps in sci-fi animation or film. The book involved three kids, and they got a message one day or something, and they eventually decoded it to be lottery numbers, and they were told to buy a submarine with it and some other things. Some weird fog starts appearing all over the place, and these white creatures start beating up on everybody else. When they lose pretty much everybody, they're just kind of sitting in the submarine, and they send a message back in time, I think. It's been a few years. Anybody know what the book is or have any hints on it? Thank you~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is "[The Tomorrow Code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2974581-the-tomorrow-code)" by Brian Falkner.

> Tane and Rebecca aren’t sure what to make of it—a sequence of 1s and
>   0s, the message looks like nothing more than a random collection of
>   alternating digits. Working to decode it, however, Tane and Rebecca
>   discover that the message contains lottery numbers . . . lottery
>   numbers that win the next random draw! Suddenly Tane and Rebecca are
>   rich, but who sent the numbers? And why? More messages follow, and
>   slowly it becomes clear—the messages are being sent back in time from
>   Tane and Rebecca’s future. Something there has gone horribly wrong,
>   and it’s up to them to prevent it from happening. As they follow the
>   messages’ cryptic instructions, Tane and Rebecca begin to suspect the
>   worst—that the very survival of the human race may be at stake

[image]

Comment: YES THAT'S IT THANK YOU SO MUCH <3