# Story with an immune response by the Earth against humans

Tags: story-identification

I'm thinking of a science fiction book I read about 5 years ago where humans are attacked by a planet-scale immune system that involves a fog containing human-sized killer T cells and other immune bodies.  Anyone recognize the story?

Comment: Could you add any more details, like when you were in HS, etc. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details.

Answer (score 3):

I would guess this is the same as [Book about kids facing world ending scenario](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197081/book-about-kids-facing-world-ending-scenario) that has just been asked, and that in turn is a duplicate of [Book involving fog and primordial soup](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79989/book-involving-fog-and-primordial-soup). In that case the book is [The Tomorrow Code by Brian Falkner](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?872435).

I don't have a copy of the book, but there is [a review on the Kirkus site here](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/brian-falkner/the-tomorrow-code/) that gives some details, and the answers to the two questions I linked above provide further details. The book does indeed involve the Earth mounting an immune response against humans and creating macrophages that travel in a fog.