# Book about kids facing world ending scenario

Tags: story-identification, books

There's a very specific book that I would like to re-read, it's been almost 5 years since I've read it and I cant find it on google.
It's about 2 kids, who are faced with a world-ending scenario. The earth creates macrophages to eat humans, and transports them using a mist of sorts.
Near the end they discover a signal from the future, and end up sending their own signal back in time. I'm sorry I cant be more specific, that's all I remember.

Answer (score 2):

Could this be [The Tomorrow Code](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6856315-the-tomorrow-code?rating=5) by Brian Falkner?

[This review](https://www.sfsignal.com/archives/2009/08/review_the_tomorrow_code_by_brian_falkner/) mentions a number of the themes you've discussed.

> Take a look at a few of the major sci-fi themes discussed: analyzing
>   data from background gamma ray radiation detectors for **messages sent
>   backwards in time, macrophages,** gene splices spiraling out of control,
>   personal submarines, genetic codes for our destruction living in our
>   own genes, time loops and causality, and more. In fact, if the
>   protagonists hadn’t been **kids**, I’d argue this was a pretty ambitious
>   novel all by itself.

[image]

Comment: And if so, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79989/book-involving-fog-and-primordial-soup